# Five red cards numbered $1,2,3,4,5$ and two black cards both numbered $5$

Tags: probability

Five red cards numbered $1,2,3,4,5$ and two black cards both numbered $5$ are randomly ordered face-down into a pile. The cards are flipped over one at a time until either the sum of the numbers on the red cards is at least $10$, or the sum of the numbers on the black cards is at least $10$. The probability that the sum of the black cards reaches $10$ first can be expressed as $a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers. What is the value of $a+b$?

#### Source

Past contest on Brilliant.org

Comment: This is a question taken from Brilliant.org, as is several other of the user's posts. Please close the discussion till 5/1. Thanks - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.

Answer (score 2):

Call it a *success* when the sum of the black cards reaches $10$ first. In order to compute the probability $p$ of a success we condition on the number $r$ of red cards at the bottom of the pile.

When $r=0$ (i.e., the bottom card is black) or $r=1$ we have a failure.

When $r=2$ the bottom two red cards can form any of the $10$ pairs of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Since $6$ of these pairs have a sum $\geq6$, which leads to a success, the probability of success in this case is ${6\over10}$.

When $r\geq3$ the bottom red cards sum to $\geq6$, which leads to a success.

It follows that the overall probability $p$ of success is given by
$$p={6\over10}P[r=2]+P[r\geq3]={6\over10}\left({5\over7}\cdot{4\over6}\cdot{2\over5}\right)+{5\over7}\cdot{4\over6}\cdot{3\over5}
={2\over5}\ .$$

This finally gives $a+b=7$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b$ are coprime positive integers, then $ab\ge 1$.  Since $ab$ represents a probability, $ab\le 1$.  Hence $a=b=1$ and $a+b=2$.

Comment: is the probability of the black card have 10 first is 1/1(a surely certain probability)?

Comment: This is a question taken from Brilliant.org, as is several other of the user's posts. Please close the discussion till 5/1. Thanks - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.